# Avoiding "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserException" when executing jQuery from code-behind

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I am using a Master Page and added jQuery script references in the HEAD section. From the content Form, whenever I try to execute `Response.Write`, I frequently get this error:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserException
```

Though I have found a way to resolve this issue for other sections of my code, I am still struggling when I have to fire jQuery code from code-behind .cs file.

I am using this way:

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>$(function(){$('#dialog:ui-dialog').dialog()};</script>");
```

Is there any way to bypass this nasty error and use Response.Write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Response.Write()` for outputting JavaScript *can* work, but it's a bit clumsy and prone to unintended consequences!

The next step up from `Response.Write()` would be using a `Literal` control as a placeholder and setting its `Text` property to your JavaScript string.

The 'better' way to do it is to use the [RegisterClientScriptBlock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock.aspx) method (or RegisterStartupScript()) of the `ClientScriptManager` class. It's simple to use and ensures your script is 'visible' to the containing Page without conflicting with any .NET quirks.